# How do I parse a number from a div string?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a site and grab the number in the 'data-itemId' field below (1234567):

```html
<div class="submission" data-itemId="1234567" data-membershipId="00000" data-page="0">
  <div class="image Image">
    <img data-imageurl="test.png" src="test.png" class="img_lightbox" alt="Test" width="455" />
    <p class="lightboxExtra cf">
      <span class="title">Test-</span>
      <span class="description"></span>
      <a href="/test?itemId=1234567">PERMALINK <i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <a href="/Test?itemId=1234567">Test-</a>
  </div>
  <div class="meta cf">
    <div class="info">
      <p>Submitted by: <a class="submittedBy" data-membershipId="00000" href="/test?id=00000">TestUser</a>
      </p>
      <p>Source: <a href="test.png" target="_blank" class="externalLink exempt">media.tumblr.com</a>
      </p>
      <p class="actions">
        <a href="" class="trigger_report" data-itemId="1234567" data-membershipId="00000">Report</a>
        <a href="/test/0000000" class="btn_modify exempt">Modify</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="light " data-itemId="1234567">
      <span class="lightNumber">469</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I have this code that helps me find a URL that also contains the same number:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://www.test.com"
URLScraped = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(URLScraped.text, 'lxml')

for Submission in soup.find_all('div', class_='submission'):
    for ID in Submission.find_all('a'):
        print ID.get('href')
```

This outputs something like this:

> /Test?itemId=1234567
>
> /Test?itemId=1234567
>
> /Test?id=0000000
>
> http://test.com/test.png

I know it does this because the code I'm using is simply searching for anything that looks like a URL within the div 'submission'.  However, I would love to be able to take the number (1234567 in this case) out of 'data-itemId' as seen in the first line of the html code.  Keep in mind, there are multiple submission divs, so I'm trying to get all numbers from 'data-membershipId' into an array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
for Submission in soup.find_all('div', 'submission'):
    print Submission['data-itemid']
```

And you confused me with your last line:

> I'm trying to get all numbers from 'data-membershipId' into an array

So do you want 'data-membershipId' in an array? I asked because you mentioned 'data-itemId' everywhere else.

Comment: Definitely meant data-itemid.  Your code works!  Thank you!